# ASP.Net page not updating - Literally the same screen from earlier (as if back was selected)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session, session-state

I have an ASP.Net application that accesses user data from a SQL database.

- Visual Studio Version 2012
- Windows Server 2012 Standard 6.2
- Sql Server 2012
- Program in Service since 11/2007 (with problem having never happened previously)

**Problem**:
First reported by 2 of my customers but I was not experiencing the problem until after a recent MS update.

Unsure of the particulars of those updates or whether it was only a coincident.

Log into application and go around to a few pages, all seems ok, than I select a new Active Company (auto filters list screens by Active Company ID from a session variable, changing active company changes the ID stored in the session variable), everything works fine for a while (1 - 4 mins) switching between screens and even different active companies, than at one point I go to a page that I've been to several times (that worked fine) and it shows everything from the last time I accessed it  (literally the identical page from a few mins ago). I change to another page and it appears to be updated, go back to the screen that did not update and it no matter what, will not update again. I query the database and it is indicating the correct active company ID and query the session variable and that too is correct.

** The strange thing is I can wait 4 -5 mins (I just stop doing anything) and than try to access the page again and now it updates.

I have been beating at this now for almost 2 weeks and have not been able to determine to source of the problem.
I literally have tried every settings for session caching I could read up on with no (or minimal) affect.
Since our software utilizes session variables to hold user variables to control their environment (like active company selection), I went to go as far as removing the session variables and making the profile.variables (requiring Sql Session management) with minimal affect).

It seems to work fine for a few minutes (or page accesses) than once it stops updating the page, it will no longer update under any circumstance.

It will occur on pretty much any combination of page changes (after changing the active company, since it will actually change data displayed).

This design has been out in the field for over 8 years now (and is routinely brought up-to-date with the latest dot.net compiler updates, .net framework and IronSpeed Designer engine updates. This error has never occurred before now. No update to the development tools took place prior to the appearance of this issue.

I tried various tests.
Test 1: 
I added java code to reset each page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function RefreshPage()
  {
    window.location.reload()
  }
</script>
```

Result: No change

Test 2:
I stopped as soon as the page did not refresh and started timing when the page would update (1 -2 mins or going back and forth between the change active company and the reports screen several times)

Result:
After 60 - 90 secs, the current page seemed to do an update (the activity icon would appear than go away) so I would than check the page the was not refreshing and it was now correct.

Since I was using the report page for my tests, I would run a report when the screen update failed, to see what active company it thought it was on (since it was also reliant on the session variable, it was bringing up the correct report data, even though the page was not indicating the correct active company. Note: Every one of our screens indicate the current user and active company name at the top, so it is easy to see when it is not updating.

Any direction as to where to look from here would be greatly appreciated, *I'm at a lost as to what to check now*.

P.S. I installed MS Message Analyzer and had it monitor up to the point where I get a failure. I have never user MS MA before so I don't have much of an idea as to what to look for, other than the operation status was indicating Found (302) for the Get and Post and Ok (200) for the page I received the problem for.

Thanks in advanced!

John R

Comment: you mean you added Javascript, not java :)  seriously though, what .net version and iis version?

Comment: .Net is 4.5.2 and 
iis is ver 8 on all our servers

Comment: I'm starting to develop a theory based on my web research and some test results.
Fact 1: I tested an earlier version of our app with same environment and development tool versions and it does not fail - ever.
Fact 2: I have to admit (embarrassingly so) that I'm a broader-line "Session Var-Junkie" - :( (I'll be mending my ways)
Fact 3: If My previous version is stable and my latest version (with many more session variables added) fails, we must have introduced the instability
Fact 4: The new app needs to be changed to eliminate (or at least minimize) session variables.

Comment: With this in mind, does anyone feel my over-use of session variables could be the culprit?
Could this be a symptom of Session variable abuse?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant to you or not, but I just remembered something about session variables I read somewhere.  Take a look at this: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1395/how-to-avoid-the-session-fixation-vulnerability-in-aspnet  does it help any?

Comment: Also, if you can verify that your previous version doesn't have this behavior, then I would recommend doing a deep comparison between the two versions looking for anything that might stand out, if you haven't done so already.

Comment: I've done quite a bit of testing, one being my previous "stable" version. It is rock solid.

Comment: What I've concluded is my new development is corrupted in some way. It is a large multi-tiered application so it tough to isolate. What I have been forced to do is take the stable version and rebuild all my changes, primarily using a tool like Beyond Compare, recreating and testing in small sections (backing up each set of changes so I can go backward once I reach a failure). It is monotonous but it is working so far. The most critical changes are working and stable.

Comment: I've had to do that before...not fun.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to check caching options. I mean caching of page, controls, javascript, and browser. As workaround I propose to add some empty paramether to your page, ajax calls. For example instead opening "default.aspx" open "default.aspx?id=someNewGoid". Also consider adding some random paramethers to your ajax calls.
Try following coe for refresh:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function S4() {
    return (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substring(1); 
}
function guid()
{
   var guid = (S4() + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-4" + S4().substr(0,3) + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + S4() + S4()).toLowerCase();
return guid;
}
  function RefreshPage()
  {
    var url = window.location;
    if (url.indexOf("?")>-1){
      url = url.substr(0,url.indexOf("?"));
    }//this par will cut of additional paramthers
    window.location = url + "?id=" + guid(); 
    window.location.reload()
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Yura!

I tried it but it did not help.
I was also getting a very strange result where I was testing, stopped on a specific page and logged out of the app. When I logged back in after a few minutes, it would take me to that exact page, that can never happen and never has before based on the structure of the login.

The default.aspx page automatically redirects to a redirect page (after a successful login) and looks up the users preferences, than redirects to that users selected start page. The page that came up is not on the selectable start page list.

Very Strange!